# Bluetooth adapter not recognized on a Dell Inspiron M5010

Tags: 12.04, dell, bluetooth

Ubuntu is not recognising my bluetooth adapter in my laptop (dell inspiron m5010) it has a bluetooth adapter built into the motherboard. I have tried reinstalling bluez, but that has just made my bluetooth settings menu disappear. It is not soft or hard blocked.

Comment: Very similar issue here with Vostro 3560. There was also a problem with WiFi, but it was resolved using recommendations at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1140595 . Unfortunately, bluetooth does not work.

Comment: Also for Inspiron 15R N5110

Comment: when you plug in the USB device, show us `lsusb` and `dmesg` output.

Answer (score 0):

Some bluetooth devices require a firmware blob to be loaded because they don't have their own firmware onboard.

This makes the device cheaper to manufacture because it doesn't need a ROM.

The Windows driver is packaged with the firmware blob, and it is loaded into RAM when the driver is initialized.

These devices can't be used in Linux because the blob is a proprietary piece of software that cannot be distributed with Linux, so when you initialize the device it acts like a zombie and the kernel gives up trying to talk to it.